# How to solve "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" in Alexa Developer Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to build a simple app for Alexa where user says the invocation name (voice control unity) and then say the utterance (temp world) described in custom intent (TempIntent) to get the output using buildSpeechletResponse i.e(temp request).
But I'm getting "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" error in Test tab in Alexa Developer Console.

I've already tried changing the intent name, invocation name, function name but nothing is working.

```
//This is index.js file lambda function

function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, response)
{
  var output = 'Welcome to Temp World';

  var reprompt = 'Type temp world';

  response(session.attributes,
   buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, reprompt,false));

  console.log("onLaunch requestId=" + launchRequest.requestId
    + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

}

function onIntent(intent, session, response) {

   console.log("onIntent requestId=" + intent.requestId
    + ", sessionId=" + session.sessionId);

   var intent = intentRequest.intent,
    intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

 if(intentName == 'TempIntent') {
   handleTempRequest(); 
   } 
else {
    throw "Invalid intent";
}
}


function handleTempRequest()
{

  buildSpeechletResponse("", "welcome to temp world", "", true);

}

function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, 
shouldEndSession) {
   return {
    outputSpeech: {
        type: "PlainText",
        text: output
    },
    card: {
        type: "Simple",
        title: title,
        content: output
    },
    reprompt: {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: repromptText
        }
    },
    shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
   };
}
```

I expected the output to be "welcome to temp world" but the JSON output is null.

JSON Input is

```
"request": {
"type": "SessionEndedRequest",
"requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.c78c093c-eb05-4eaa-8f23-16037059e61f",
"timestamp": "2019-05-09T12:23:34Z",
"locale": "en-US",
"reason": "ERROR",
"error": {
    "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
    "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
   }
  }
```

[Image showing Alexa conversation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X7yK.png)

Comment: Are you using `AWS lambda` function? If yes, add the CloudWatch logs here please.

Comment: "errorMessage": "Exception: ReferenceError: intentRequest is not defined"

Comment: I have "TempIntent" intent already in my developer console with "temp world" sample utterance built in it.

Comment: Even I am getting the same error without anything on JSON output.

Comment: Thanks to @pedro.olimpio for suggesting checking CloudWatch logs. I'm developing my first skill and was getting the same error, and I realized my .js file containing strings had syntax errors in it (I was using apostrophes and forgot a comma). The logs didn't say anything about that unfortunately, I just noticed it on my own. However I was still getting the error, and in that case the logs did describe the error, which was I was referencing an Intent that I had deleted.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the version of node.js you are using.
2. In the lambda function click on the test tab and test every intent, there you will find the problem.